# run any code in another isolate in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

asked another question on how to pass BuildContext to compute method ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698042/pass-buildcontext-to-compute))

here's another one:

I have to decode a big chunk of data on the main thread since "compute" doesn't accept anything other than

> null, num, bool, double, String, instances of SendPort, and lists and maps whose elements are any of these

so the question is how to run this in another isolate to not freeze the UI (which it does now on the main isolate) :

```
utf8.decode(Uint8list Object);
```

Comment: you can pass primitive types only, like `String` for example

Comment: so is there no way of running this in the background? worker thread? i don't want this to block/freeze UI @pskink

Comment: there is a way: pass primitive data

Comment: so what is your input data which processing takes so long? some string taken from a remote web api? a file? anything else?

Comment: it's an encrypted video file (100Mb when not encrypted) @pskink

Comment: and what stops you from opening that file in `compute` function callback?

Comment: just tired :D , will think better tomorrow , thank you @pskink

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: yes you were right , you can always use compute somewhere else to make it work. +1 @pskink